# Regex containing mailaddresses but not value=

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

how I can catch all mailaddresses from html but ignore addresses which are form values. For example:

```
    <p>Mail: anymail@example.com</p>
   ...
    <input value="anymail@example.com">
   ...
    <a href="mailto:anymail@example.com">Kontakt: <span>anymail@example.com</span></a>
```

I need all addresses, but not the address from the input field (it is a form value).

To match addresses I have:

```
(mailto:|)[a-z0-9_\.\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,}+)
```

Comment: You need to parse the HTML with a DOMDocument first to exclude the `value` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to parse HTML it's not a good idea. Nevertheless, an easier approach would be to strip all emails that are input values, and then match all the reminding emails.

Here's an example using your regex to match emails.

```
$html = preg_replace("/value=[\"'][a-z0-9_\.\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,}[\"']/", "", $html);

preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9_\.\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,}/", $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches); //will output all emails but the one inside value.
```